# Can MOSS's AssetUrlSelector browse sub folders in lists?

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-2007

I keep getting a 'List does not exist' error whenever I try and use AssetUrlSelector to browse a subfolder in Microsoft Office SharePoint Server (MOSS).

To reproduce this behaviour: Add a Summary Link Web Part and add a new link.  Click 'Browse' this will open the AssetPortalBrowser.aspx dialog.  Browse to a list that contains sub folders and double click a sub folder.  The error is rasied at this point.

All of my MOSS installations exhibit this behaviour.  Although I can understand why it may not be able to handle the browsing of sub folders, it does seem odd that it throws an error.

I'd be interested to know if anyone else has this issue or if anyone can confirm if this is correct behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I confirm this problem occurs with MOSS 2007 SP2 (April 2009 CU). It works fine with document libraries but not custom lists (I used a links list).

You should raise a support call with Microsoft. This is clearly a bug with the product so it should not cost anything. I've checked the June 2009 CU fix list and can't see anything that would fix this issue.

Comment: +1 Thanks, that was all I was after. Thought I was going mad. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You have to ensure that your user has the permission level "Browse directories" on the root web. You can either put your user inside one group that has that permission level or create your own role to contain that permission level.

Comment: Thanks however this happens for all users including site collection administrators and those who have browse permissions for the list they are browsing.